# Hybris faceted search

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I have a requirement whereby I have to implement a faceted search,where a user is taken through some questions and suggested a list of products on Hybris.Any approach to help me get started?

Answer (score 0):

Solr supports facet search on its own. Hybris leverages this via the solr configuration. You can manage this through the impex file. There are a lot of fields on SolrIndexedProperty, but I think these are the ones required to control facet search - **facet=true**, **facetType**, and **facetSort**.

```
INSERT_UPDATE SolrIndexedProperty ; ... facet[default = true] ; facetType(code) ; facetSort(code) ; ...
                                  ; ...                       ; MultiSelectOr   ; Alpha           ; ...
```

Here's the full impex statement, in case I missed something.

```
INSERT_UPDATE SolrIndexedProperty ; solrIndexedType(identifier)[unique = true] ; name[unique = true] ; type(code) ; isAlpha[default = false] ; isNumeric[default = false] ; isAlphaNumeric[default = false] ; sortableType(code) ; currency[default = false] ; localized[default = false] ; multiValue[default = false] ; facet[default = true] ; facetType(code) ; facetSort(code) ; priority ; visible ; useForSpellchecking[default = false] ; useForAutocomplete[default = false] ; fieldValueProvider                 ; valueProviderParameter                                             ; facetDisplayNameProvider ; customFacetSortProvider         ; topValuesProvider        ; rangeSets(name) ; displayName ; includeInResponse [default=true]
                                  ; yourProductType                            ; colorFacet          ; string     ; true                     ;                            ;                                 ;                    ;                           ;                            ;                             ;                       ; MultiSelectOr   ; Alpha           ; 7500     ; true    ;                                      ;                                     ; colorValueProvider                 ;                                                                    ;                          ; facetNameSortProviderAscending  ; defaultTopValuesProvider ;                 ; "Color"              ;false
```

Comment: @ryanb,thanks a lot,but I think some other steps are also needed from the view of populating and navigating from the component and creating a query